# xsl replace source xml by second xml with untouched element that not exist at second xml

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have xsl transformation that copy element from source XML and replace elements from second xml that match and generate finaly XML. It working, but when a element not exist at a second xml than copy element empty ().
I need copy untouched elements from source that not exist at second xml.

For example: First XML contained

```
<SHOP>
 <SHOPITEM>
  <CATEGORYTEXT>some ways</CATEGORYTEXT>
  <PRODUKT_ID>80002158</PRODUKT_ID>
  <PRODUCT>Zvedák 5t</PRODUCT>
  <PRODUCTNAME>Zvedák 5t</PRODUCTNAME>
  <ZBOZI_PRODUCTNO>t2</ZBOZI_PRODUCTNO>
  <OZNACENO>0</OZNACENO>
 </SHOPITEM>
 <SHOPITEM>
  <CATEGORYTEXT>VÝPRODEJ</CATEGORYTEXT>
  <PRODUKT_ID>80002419</PRODUKT_ID>
  <PRODUCT>3d Dochucovací sada Renga</ZPRODUCT>
  <PRODUCTNAME>3d Dochucovací sada Renga</PRODUCTNAME>
  <ZBOZI_PRODUCTNO>vv61</ZBOZI_PRODUCTNO>
  <OZNACENO>0</OZNACENO>
 </SHOPITEM>
</SHOP>
```

Second xml contain ...

```
<dataroot>
 <zbozi_FEED_DATA>
  <ZBOZI_CELA_CESTA>Heureka.cz | Auto-moto | Autodíly | Ramena řízení</ZBOZI_CELA_CESTA>
  <PRODUKT_ID>80002158</PRODUKT_ID>
  <ZBOZI_PRODUCT>Zvedák - panenka 5t</ZBOZI_PRODUCT>
  <ZBOZI_PRODUCTNAME>Zvedák - panenka 5t</ZBOZI_PRODUCTNAME>
  <ZBOZI_PRODUCTNO>t2</ZBOZI_PRODUCTNO>
  <OZNACENO>0</OZNACENO>
 </zbozi_FEED_DATA>
</dataroot>
```

And desire output xml:

```
 <SHOP>
  <SHOPITEM>
   <zbozi_FEED_DATA>
   <CATEGORYTEXT>Heureka.cz | Auto-moto | Autodíly | Ramena řízení</CATEGORYTEXT>
   <PRODUKT_ID>80002158</PRODUKT_ID>
   <PRODUCT>Zvedák - panenka 5t</PRODUCT>
   <PRODUCTNAME>Zvedák - panenka 5t</PRODUCTNAME>
   <ZBOZI_PRODUCTNO>t2</ZBOZI_PRODUCTNO>
   <OZNACENO>0</OZNACENO>
  </SHOPITEM>
  <SHOPITEM>
   <CATEGORYTEXT>VÝPRODEJ</CATEGORYTEXT>
   <PRODUKT_ID>80002419</PRODUKT_ID>
   <PRODUCT>3d Dochucovací sada Renga</PRODUCT>
   <PRODUCTNAME>3d Dochucovací sada Renga</PRODUCTNAME>
   <ZBOZI_PRODUCTNO>vv61</ZBOZI_PRODUCTNO>
   <OZNACENO>0</OZNACENO>
  </SHOPITEM>
</SHOP>
```

But now is wrong output:

```
 <SHOP>
  <SHOPITEM>
   <zbozi_FEED_DATA>
    <CATEGORYTEXT>Heureka.cz | Auto-moto | Autodíly | Ramena řízení</CATEGORYTEXT>
    <ITEM_IDD>80002158</ITEM_ID>
    <PRODUCT>Zvedák - panenka 5t</PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCTNAME>Zvedák - panenka 5t</PRODUCTNAME>
    <ZBOZI_PRODUCTNO>t2</ZBOZI_PRODUCTNO>
    <OZNACENO>0</OZNACENO>
   </SHOPITEM>
   <SHOPITEM>
  **<CATEGORYTEXT/>**
    <ITEM_ID>80002419</ITEM_ID>
  **<PRODUCT/>**
  **<PRODUCTNAME/>**
    <ZBOZI_PRODUCTNO>vv61</ZBOZI_PRODUCTNO>
    <OZNACENO>0</OZNACENO>
  </SHOPITEM>
 </SHOP>
```

And my XSL tranformation is there :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="ZBOZI_CELA_CESTA" />
 <xsl:param name="clientXml" select="'FEED_DATA.xml'" />
 <xsl:variable name="client" select="document(`$`clientXml)//zbozi_FEED_DATA" />
 <xsl:template match="SHOPITEM/CATEGORYTEXT">
  <CATEGORYTEXT>
   <xsl:value-of select="$client[PRODUKT_ID=current()/../ITEM_ID]/ZBOZI_CELA_CESTA" />
  </CATEGORYTEXT>
 </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="SHOPITEM/PRODUCT">
 <PRODUCT>
<xsl:value-of select="$client[PRODUKT_ID=current()/../ITEM_ID]/ZBOZI_PRODUCT" />
 </PRODUCT>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="SHOPITEM/PRODUCTNAME">
<PRODUCTNAME>
<xsl:value-of select="$client[PRODUKT_ID=current()/../ITEM_ID]/ZBOZI_PRODUCTNAME" />
</PRODUCTNAME>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please, can anyone help ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please ask specific question, try coding something and show us where you failed. Please do not ask broad questions or ask us to complete your homework assignments.

Comment: Hello Alexis,I am failed right there because more than two months  I am tried different setttings of this xsl, but still not working. And still if the this elements missed at second XML than after transfomation are the elements empty at finaly XML.. And empty element I have to check every day and add contain manualy. Therefore I do not know how do it.

Answer (score 0):

Im not comepletely sure what you are looking for, but it seems ot me like you want to get either the ZBOZI_CELA_CESTA or the CATEGORYTEXT into your node. That is accomplished like this:

```
 <xsl:template match="SHOPITEM/CATEGORYTEXT">
  <CATEGORYTEXT>
   <xsl:value-of select="$client[PRODUKT_ID=current()/../ITEM_ID]/ZBOZI_CELA_CESTA | $client[PRODUKT_ID=current()/../ITEM_ID]/CATEGORYTEXT"/>
  </CATEGORYTEXT>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Christian,thank you , but it is not what I looking for.  In my case I need copy CATEGORYTEXT if ZBOZI_CELA_CESTA is missing . Mostly groove a products at source feed and second feed are created manualy with delay. So if element or node is missing I need use original element from source feed.  And finaly feed will not have empty elements.